# How can I set filtering indexes on columns like price?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do not understand concept of filtering indexes.

I saw a example like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_customer_inactive
ON customer(active)
WHERE active = 0;
```

But maybe I have a product table where I filter of pricing.

One user may input one instead of two so I have to say this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_customer_inactive
ON customer(active)
WHERE price = Whatever
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_customer_inactive ON customer(active) WHERE active = 0;
```

This creates an index named `idx_customer_inactive` on the **active column** of the **customer table**. The WHERE clause specifies that the index should only include rows where the active column has a value of 0. The following query could benefit from that index:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE active = 0;
```

This query filters the customer table to only include rows where the active column has a value of 0. Because the idx_customer_inactive index only includes these rows, the database can use the index to quickly find the relevant rows and return the results of the query faster.

Regarding this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_customer_inactive -- this name should include "price"
ON customer(active)                -- on the customer table? referencing the active column?
WHERE price = Whatever             -- is there a price column in the customer table?
```

Comment: Hey I know this with active but price can be dynamic it can be 1 or 500 or 599, so what should I use in "Whatever" ?

Comment: Any valid value of price, but it is so unlikely that anyone would create an index of price equal to 100.00 or ,= 550.19,  or any "whatever".  The example of "active" is just more realistic.